# PhpStorm execute terminal command after each save

Tags: cordova, terminal, phpstorm, command-line-interface, settings

I'm creating an app with Cordova but for some reason I can't get the BrowserSync plugin installed, more people are writing about it.

The main reason I want it, is to see UI changes in effect when I made them. I found that `cordova serve` only spins up a server that is able to display the state of the app as it was at the moment of firing up the server.

I figured maybe I could execute a command after each save operation (`CTRL + C && cordova serve`.

On the PhpStorm forums I found an [old request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206328939-Saving-and-running-terminal-commands-on-shortcut-file-save) about similar functionality but I can't seem to find a way to implement this.

Anyone knows if this can be done with PhpStorm?

Comment: File Watchers: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm or manually via External Tools: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm

Comment: I can add nothing to the old post you refer to/previous comment. You can set up `cordova serve` as a file watcher and turn off `immediate synchronization` for it to make sure the watcher is triggered on explicit **Save** only